# Xcode 7.1 upload App error

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

Error code is 1070
"You must be an Itunes Connect Admin or Technical user in order to deliver content or metadata"

The account's role is agent and has all roles of Itunes Connect, and I also tried another account in the same team whose role is admin and developer role of Itunes Connect, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try using the Application loader? or Xcode archive?

Comment: Both I used and got the same error.

Comment: Have you checked `Benefits & Resources` in this link: https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/. Please verify the type of account from this link, it should possibly lies in `Indivisual` and `Organization` type. Also look at this answer: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/191794/which-ios-developer-account-should-i-sign-up-for

Comment: I have the same issue.  I was able to upload builds yesterday, but not today.  I'm guessing it has to do with the new roles introduced today:

"We’ve introduced new and updated existing user roles in Users and Roles, so you can better manage your team’s access to your apps on iTunes Connect"

Comment: so what can we do? just wait?

Comment: Same Issue here... Admin is the ONLY role that works. App Manager, Technical, etc do not.

Comment: please escalate this bug to Apple here -https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit.php

Answer (score 5):

iTunes Connect support says the workaround is to just change the team member's role to Admin, then upload should work. <s>After upload, you can now change back the team member's role to its original role. Subsequent uploads *might* work but for other's it still won't.</s>
**Update**: Reverting to original role results in error again, so you need to be Admin to upload builds. As of now, there are no news of a fix.

EDIT:

Source: 
[Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/25968)
and tried it myself.

Comment: Can you tell me how to change the role to Admin? 'Cause other accounts in the team can not switch to Admin role from other roles like Developer. And the app manager can not change role because all the role buttons seems to be disabled.

Comment: Only the Admin user can change the roles of members. So if you're account is not and Admin, you have to ask your Admin to change it for you.

Comment: I am the Admin user already, I have all roles because I am the Agent. But the Apple keep telling me that I am not Admin or Technical(which is now apparently doesn't exist anymore in itunes connect), and I can change other members' role from Developer to Admin.

Comment: That's weird. You should be able to upload your build when you are an Admin. Try removing your account from Xcode then adding it again.

Comment: Can you give a citation source?

Comment: Apparently it's a bug from Apple side. My solution is to go to Developer Member Center and transfer the agent account to another account.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue on **Xcode 11.3** for uploading.

**It seems a bug for Xcode.**

I had 3 accounts added to Xcode and just one of them was an Admin.
I asked the Owner to change my role to Admin but i got this error again.

It's stupid but i only had one account left that even not used in the project!!

So i asked again to add this account and set its role to Admin and the error was still remained.

So i went to the accounts added in **Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts** and removed all other accounts except the one was Owner, Admin of this project and problem solved!!

**The solution worked for me was just to remove other accounts which are not Owner, Admin role from Xcode.**

Comment: Thanks Bro, you saved my life. I hate Apple, they find bugs in our application. But they can't find the bugs in their own Xcode or iTunes connect.

Comment: @MandeepSingh I agree, it's really annoying.

Answer (score 2):

1. Find your accounts, Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts;
2. Delete all accounts;
3. Login accounts again;
4. Close Xcode;
5. Open Xcode again.

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

My problem:

I've just upload successfully at 4pm

Then at 5pm, I got this error message (I wonder why!):

> you must be an admin or technical user in order to deliver content or metadata.

My solution:

Menu XCode > Preference

Tab Account

Remove others AppleID account or move your needed Apple ID account to the top of the list.

Upload again and luckily it's successful

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 9 still has this problem, too.

My account is already assigned as **ADMIN** role on the App Store Connect. But when I upload app by using Xcode still encounter this issue *"You must be an Itunes Connect Admin or Technical user in order to deliver content or metadata"(1070)*.

My solution is export the .ipa file, then using *[Application Loader](https://help.apple.com/itc/apploader/)* to upload .ipa. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue after updating Xcode to 10.2.1. Here is my solution.

1. Open Application Loader. To open it, goto Xcode menu>> Open Developer Tool and click Application Loader.
2. Now check which Apple ID you are connected to on top left corner of Application Loader. Here is an image.[image]
3. This is primary Apple ID Xcode is connected to. So, make sure you have Developer/Admin access to this particular Apple ID to upload app. Or you can Sign Out existing Apple ID currently showing in Application Loader and Sign in with Apple ID you are trying to upload build file.

In my case, instead of signing out, I gave admin permission to `info@cninfotech.com` account and I was able to upload my app.

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same error under these circumstances:

- I have two Apple Developer accounts, one with emailA@foo.com and one with emailB@foo.com
- I added emailB@foo.com as a user with the role "Marketing" to the account emailA@foo.com

Now the App Store seems to have been confused, thinking that the marketing account emailB@foo.com wanted to upload a binary, which is not allowed.

Had to delete my emailB@foo.com account from Xcode and tried the upload again and it worked

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your (apple id from which you are trying to upload build) session has been expired. In my case it was expired. You need to login again.

Check by using below steps

XCode>Preferences>Accounts

Answer (score 0):

Removed all other accounts which is related to that app(uploading app) except the one was App Manager, Admin and may be developer of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Though the role is Admin, i got this error. I solved it by uploading the same build using [transporter](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12) app by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was:

Remove others accounts in **Xcode** -> **Preferences** -> **Accounts**

or move your needed Apple ID account to the top of the list.

Answer (score -1):

I finally overcome this annoying problem, the approach is to transfer the agent to another account.